# Sum elements of an array

Tags: arrays, assembly, sum, mips

It is my first time here, so I want to apologize for any grammar/spelling mistakes in English. I have this Assembly program that sums an array's elements. I calculate the sum in variable `suma` which is declared as `.space 4`. 
 My question is the following: Is it possible for the sum to end up with the value of 0 when n=0 not by declaring it as `.word 0` nor `sw $t0, suma`, but to code some lines after `end:` right before the end of the program?
Any answer is highly appreciated!

```
suma: .space 4
a: .word 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1
n: .word 7
i: .space 4

.text
main:

li $t0, 0
sw $t0, i
lw $t1, n

repeat:


bge $t0, $t1, end

add $t0, $t0, $t0  
add $t0, $t0, $t0

lw $t0, a($t0)

lw $t1, suma 
add $t1,$t1,$t0
sw $t1, suma

lw $t0, i
addi $t0, $t0, 1
sw $t0, i

lw $t1, n

j repeat

end:

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: you can do this in mysql : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Comment: I know that there are many other ways/languages in which I can write the program but it needs to be in Assembly. Some other ideas?..

Comment: It's unclear why the methods of setting `suma` to 0 that you've already mentioned aren't sufficient. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a register ($t3 for example) initialized with 0 and make the sum in that register. After exiting the loop, you will store the word in suma. Sorry for the last comment (I forgot to log in).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a register initialized with 0 and then make the sum in that register. After exiting the loop, you will store the word in suma.